# How do you compile your entire game into an installer

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, compilation, installation, sdl-2

So I made a test game that I wanted someone else on a different computer to open.
I used Flexera's limited edition installshield (I'm on visual studio 2012) .
So I successfully made the launcher along with it's .msi.

In the include files step of the flexera assistant (I tried to just include primary output but I get some kind of error), I included the vc_redist file, the .exe file, and all the .dlls to be used.
The thing is that the other person kept on getting a missing error looking for
MSVCP110D
P110D

I told that person to install the vc_redist but it still had the same output. 
(But I tried installing on my laptop and it worked)

So I'm here to ask (for those who got theirs to work) how did you make your launcher?
(I don't mind it being the direct .exe without the launcher at the very least I just need it to work)

Comment: MSVCP110D is for the "debug" builds. Try build in "release" mode.

Comment: I did try but if I do try then the SDL2 libraries that I used won't be linked...

Comment: Do you have them built to the same runtimes (all dependencies built in "release") and in the "additional library" paths (for release)?

Comment: Okay, I just finished and now they're linking. Thanks :) so that means MSVCP110D is eliminated, P110D should be the only one remaining.

Comment: The debug versions of the Visual C++ runtime are _not_ redistributable. Compile in release mode and link to the release version of third party libraries then package into an installer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally fixed it thanks to the comments of some helpful people.

Apparently, I have to switch the mode from configuration

Right click the solution and go to properties

Go to configuration properties then click configuration manager at the top right of the window that just appeared, from there on, switch from debug to release.

Relink all your libraries and in Pre-compiled header, choose create. This creates a pre-compiled header in the Release folder.

Make sure that your pre-compiled header, in my case stdafx.h, is on the first line of EVERY CPP file and not in the header files.

Compile.

In the install shield, instead of linking the files from the DEBUG folder, link it from the Release folder and that should work.